# Initializing an NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, nsdictionary

Is there any difference between initializing an NSDictionary by this way:

```
self.myData = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
[self.myData initWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
```

or this way:

```
self.myData = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
```

Because the reason I'm asking this question is the first one is not working. I'm new and curious to know why?

Here's My Code :-

[image]

Comment: Please post code instead linking to png

Comment: It's because you are allocating and initializing your dictionary twice. alloc it once and then set it's key and value(add objects). In your second way you are allocating and initializing ones and set objects withing it so it is working!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first version calls init twice, which is a very, very bad thing to do in most cases, but especially bad for built-in classes like NSDictionary. I have never tried this, but it *should* crash because you initialised an immutable dictionary, and the second attempt to initialise would modify it.

Comment: I disagree with the statement "and the second attempt to initialise would modify it" as mutability is not an issue when `alloc`/`init` is involved.  I don't see why it's been accepted as *the* answer but I expect it's because of the amount of rep the answerer.

Comment: but that's not what I'm Asking you are not getting me I already solved it before asking the question by simply doing :- self.myData=[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys]; I just wanted to ask the difference and i think now i understand the whole point.@Droppy

Answer (score 4):

You can initialize your dictionary in this way:

```
self.myData = @{ @"key1" : object1, 
                 @"key2" : object2
                 // etc.
               };
```